# Div Sizing Issue

Tags: css, html

I'm having issues with the sizing of a `<div>` that has another `<div>` inside and an `<p>` element inside:

HTML:

```
 <div class="head">

         <div class="head_in">

             <p id="head_title"> BETA 1.7 </p>

         </div>

     </div>
```

CSS:

```
.head
{
 width: 100%; height: 20%; background-color: #000000; 
}

.head_in
{
     display: block;
}

#head_title
{
         font-size: 0.6 em; color: red; text-align: right;
}
```

Outcome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkDQm.jpg

Basically I want to make the div smaller and when I use padding it simply makes it bigger, I have tried changing the height but even at 1% or 90% for that matter it still decides to stay the same, I have also taken out the `.head_in` div but still nothing. Any help appreciated!

Comment: It does changes using safari and chrome on Mac OS when I change height from 20% to 1%. Wondering what platform and browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Height of `<body>` is not full, while `html` is always at least viewport height. You can do:

```
body { height: 100% }
```

To make percent heights work. Or use [viewport](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) heights.

```
.head { height: 20vh }
```

Comment: Hmmm, that's interesting I think you're right and that viewport height is much better. Thanks!

Comment: I would be careful using VH in production see answer below

Comment: @Matt What do you mean? Browser support is [green skies](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units). I can't imagine why anybody would want to support any older browsers than that. 73% support, plus much more if you are a giving the "we do not support IE" screen for all IE (which is standard).

Answer (score 0):

Height sizes of tags are not inherited like width sizes.  You must assign a height for every tag or you must let the content automatically set the height.  For 100% height EVERY parent must have 100%.  This includes the HTML tag && Body tag.  therefore:
The answer above missed that the HTML needs a height of 100% also:

**HTML**

```
<div class="head">

     <div class="head_in">

         <p id="head_title"> BETA 1.7 </p>

     </div>

 </div>
```

**css**

```
html, body {
 height:100%;   

}
.head
{
 width: 100%; height: 20%; background-color: #000000; 
}

.head_in
{
     display: block;
}

#head_title
{
         font-size: 0.6 em; color: red; text-align: right;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Aqk5/)
I would be careful using the viewport height if your site is going to production.  It doesn't work on very many browers yet.

Comment: Hmm, yes I don't know why I never ran into this issue before, i've done similar things but it always worked without doing that. Guess I'll keep it in mind and apply it now. Thanks!